# Internal Error when using angularCompilerOptions.baseUrl

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-cli, tsconfig

I have an Angular 14 project (generated by angular CLI) in Intellij, everything is working as expected, but with relative imports from components.

Now I would like all imports from the same base directory, so I just tried to :

- add angularCompilerOptions.baseUrl = "./" in the tsconfig.json
- add compilerOptions.baseUrl = "./" in the tsconfig.json
- update imports automatically with Intellij, new imports are now defined from src

Sample: `import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";)`

But now when I run ng serve, I got this error:

```
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...file:///xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-4NRCP3Y6.js:124
    throw new Error(`Internal Error: absoluteFrom(${path}): path is not absolute`);
          ^

Error: Internal Error: absoluteFrom(src/app/app.component.ts): path is not absolute
    at absoluteFrom (file:///media/xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-4NRCP3Y6.js:124:11)
    at file:///xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-J6AVV3MN.js:5740:57
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ComponentDecoratorHandler.analyze (file:///xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-J6AVV3MN.js:5739:51)
    at TraitCompiler.analyzeTrait (file:///xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-J6AVV3MN.js:3388:30)
    at analyze (file:///xxx/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-J6AVV3MN.js:3359:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

What is going on ?

UPDATE: I rollbacked my changes to get something working, and then I updated only ONE import starting from "src" and this time the error is :

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Internal Error: absoluteFrom(src/app/components/shared/report-list/stacktrace-dialog/stacktrace-dialog.component.ts): path is not absolute
```

UPDATE 2: I have no idea why, with a new test, I have now another behaviour...

If we just update tsconfig with:

```
angularCompilerOptions.baseUrl = "./"   # or "."
```

Then it compiles (and works) with the following warning, and Intellij marks the import as invalid.

```
./src/app/app.component.ts - Warning: Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths.
Invalid dependencies may lead to broken watching and caching.
As best effort we try to convert all invalid values to absolute paths and converting globs into context dependencies, but this is deprecated behavior.
Loaders: Pass absolute paths to this.addDependency (existing files), this.addMissingDependency (not existing files), and this.addContextDependency (directories).
Plugins: Pass absolute paths to fileDependencies (existing files), missingDependencies (not existing files), and contextDependencies (directories).
Globs: They are not supported. Pass absolute path to the directory as context dependencies.
The following invalid values have been reported:
 * "src/app/core/services/theme.service.ts"
```

If I also change the tsconfig with

```
compilerOptions.baseUrl = "./"  # or "."
```

Then I got the above warning twice, but at least Intellij recognizes the imports since it reads this value in tsconfig.

It looks like something is unstable, I even not added code since the first test, I just re-organize files in directories.

Do not work on stackblitz either:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f2uafy?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try add this

```
 angularCompilerOptions.baseUrl = "./src" in the tsconfig.json
```

Comment: It do not compile, unless I also change "compilerOptions" to "./src" (and update the import of course), but then I have a warning displayed twice, as explained in the updated question, it works but with dangerous warnings.

Comment: If you can create app on stackblitz it will everyone to figure out

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f2uafy?file=src/app/test/test.component.ts